# What is the difference between "for all" and "there exists" in set builder notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, quantifiers

I'm having trouble with a specific example of set builder notation, and I'm hoping someone can help.
Here's an example of what I am having trouble with:
$$A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : \exists x \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } n=2^x\}$$
$$B = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : \forall x \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } n=2^x\}$$
Both of these sets are supposed to be equivalent to set $S$ where
$$S = \{...,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},1,2,4,...\}$$
My question is what is the difference between set $A$ and set $B$? Is one of the notations more accurate than the other?

Comment: The second one isn't really mathematical-grammatically correct to me.

Comment: The second one is the empty set. You want the set of all $n$ natural numbers such that for all $x$ a natural number we have $n = 2^x.$ Obviously, no natural number satisfies this.

Comment: Both $A$ and $B$ are defined to be sets of natural numbers, so they can't be equal to $S$, which contains fractions.

Comment: Normally, one writes $\exists x\in \Bbb N, n=2^x$, there should not be an "and", or it should rather be a "such that". Same comment with $\forall$, where one usually put nothing.

Comment: To the downvoters: Do not downvote purely because the question contains factual errors. Do that to answers only. If people already got it right they wouldn't ask here anyway.

Comment: I would write: $\{n:\exists x\left(x\in\mathbb{Z}\wedge n=2^{n}\right)\}$. $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is wrong, since you have fractions and if you correct to $n\in\mathbb{Q}$, it would be redundant, since $x\in\mathbb{Z}\wedge n=2^{n}$ will do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither are particularly accurate, but that's because in part I think you want $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ instead.

I would also insist on the use of "such that" in lieu of "and" in $A$, and no such connective in $B$, since they just don't read right. "There exists some $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n=2^x$" is just a strange statement grammatically since, after all, there are indeed elements of $\mathbb{N}$. "Such that" is a lot more appropriate here, since you're using that $x$ to define $n$.

If $n \in B$, then we need $n = 2^x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, this is nonsense, as if $x,x' \in \mathbb{Z}$ are distinct then $n=2^x = 2^{x'}$ but this requires $x=x'$, a contradiction.

I get what $B$ is trying to go for - the set of all powers of $2$ - but written as-is, it does not properly convey that.

Comment: Thanks! You were right, it is $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, I just thought of it wrong while typing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, $A=\left\{2,4,8,16,\ldots\right\}$, whereas $B=\emptyset$. This second assertion comes from the fact that there is no $n\in\Bbb N$ which is equal to **every** power of $2$ with natural exponent. On the other hand, the *natural* numbers which are a power of $2$ for **some** natural exponent are precisely the numbers $2,4,8,16,\ldots$ (unless you consider $0$ a natural number, in which case you should add $1$ to the list).

Comment: Can you elaborate, what is wrong here:  $n=2^x,~ x\in\mathbb N$ yields $n\in\mathbb N$, such that  $n:=2,4,8\cdots $ . Not ?

Comment: @lonestudent *No!* As I wrote in my answer, the expression $n=2^x$, $\forall x\in\Bbb N$ means that $n$ is equal to **every** power of $2$ with natural exponent.

Comment: If we define $$B = \{n \in \mathbb{N_{>0}} :  x \in \mathbb{N_{>0}} \text{ and } n=2^x\}$$ this produces $$B:=2,4,8\cdots $$ Right ?

Comment: @lonestudent Not really. That $B$ is meaningless. After the “:” sign, there should be a proposition depending on $n$ (and only on $n$), but that's not the case here.

Comment: Or if we define  $$B = \{n : n=2^x, x \in \mathbb{N_{>0}}\}$$ is it also incorrect ?

Comment: @lonestudent Again, I would call it “meaningless” rather than “incorrect”.

Answer (score 3):

When you're having trouble understanding the basic meaning of some expression like $$A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : \exists x \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } n=2^x\}$$ it can be helpful to separate the basic meaning from the details of the mathematics.  That way you can think about the logic without being distracted by stuff about powers of $2$.  Instead of this example, let's look at an example with the same structure but no arithmetic:

$$C = \{\text{a person $n$ in the world} : \exists \text { person $x$} \text{ and $n$ is the mother of $x$}  \}$$

Here I've replaced $\Bbb N$ with the set of people in the world, and the property “$n=2^x$” with “$n$ is the mother of $x$”.  Powers are complicated and maybe unfamiliar, but everyone has lots of practice thinking about mothers.

Here $C$ is the set of all people who are someone's mother.  Your mom is in this set, because there exists a person $x$ (namely you) that she is the mother of. But your dad is not in this set because he is not the mother of anyone.  Queen Elizabeth I is also not in this set, because she was not anyone's mother.

$$D = \{\text{a person $n$ in the world} : \forall \text { person $x$} \text{ and $n$ is the mother of $x$}  \}$$

This says something very different: person $n$ is in this set if they are the mother of $x$ for *every* person $x$.  That is, this is the set of people who are *everyone's* mother.  Is your mom in this set?  No, because she is not my mother and $D$ is the set of people who are the mother of *every* person $x$, including me.

Of course there is no person at all who is everyone's mother, so $D$ is empty.  Your set $B$ is empty for the same reason: there is no number $n$ that is equal to $2^x$ for *every* $x$.

Comment: Can you explain why this notation is incorrect, I just need to understand what is wrong and what is correct : $$B = \{n : n=2^x, x \in \mathbb{N_{>0}}\}$$ Why this notation is meaningless, exactly ?

Comment: It's because $x$ is what is called a “free variable”.  Consider this example: We want the set of people $n$ such that $n$ is the mother of $x$.  Who is in the set?  It's impossible to say, because I didn't tell you who $x$ is! [Here's a post I wrote that discusses this in more detail](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/802412/25554).

Comment: What is the fundamental difference between these notations : The set of even numbers $$B:=\{2n\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$$ and $$B:=\{2^n\mid n\in\mathbb N_{>0}\}$$  Do you think that, both notations are incorrect/meaningless ? Thank you.

Comment: No, neither is.

Comment: @lonestudent I've replied to your queries in my answer below.

Comment: An excellent explanation as always, and perhaps you passed over it in silence because it has been well discussed in the other answers, but it is perhaps also worth emphasising that the word "and" simply does not belong: if it is to operate at all, it must operate on propositions; and "$\exists x \in \mathbb N$" and "$\forall x \in \mathbb N$ are both binders, not propositions—but, even if we managed to regard them as trivial propositions (like, for example, $\exists x \in \mathbb N, \top$), as some comments have implicitly done, then the $x$ is out of scope in the other proposition $2^x = n$.

Comment: I left that out because I wanted to deal with the main issue and with the question as asked, rather than writing a long answer that covered every aspect of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The abbreviation $$∃x{∈}\mathbb N$$ is short for $$\text{there exists some natural $x$  such that$\ldots$}\\\text{for some natural $x,\ldots.$}$$ Since it isn't a sentence (and doesn't mean “some natural number exists”), the line

> $$A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : \exists x \in \mathbb{N} \color{red}{\text{ and }} n=2^x\}$$

is not meaningful until we delete the “and”:
\begin{align}A_\text{new} &=  \{n \in \mathbb{N} : \exists x {\in} \mathbb{N}\;n=2^x\}\\&=\text{the set of naturals such that }\textbf{each}\text{, for some natural $x,$ equals $2^x$}\\&= \left\{n: \;n \in \mathbb{N} \quad\text{and}\quad\exists x\, (x\in\mathbb{N}\quad\text{and}\quad n=2^x)\,\right\}\\&= \left\{n:\; \exists x\, (n \in \mathbb{N} \quad\text{and}\quad x\in\mathbb{N}\quad\text{and}\quad n=2^x)\,\right\}\\&= \left\{n:\; \exists x\, (x\in\mathbb{N}\quad\text{and}\quad n=2^x)\,\right\}\\&=\color{brown}{\{n : \exists x {\in} \mathbb{N}\;n=2^x\}}\\&=\color{brown}{\{2^x:x\in\mathbb N\}}\\&=\text{the set of values of the form $2^x$ such that $x$ is natural}\\&=\{2,4,8,16,\ldots\}.\end{align} In the above, the sets written in brown are notational alternatives to each other (Wikipedia says that the latter is an extension of the set-builder notation). In this case the domain specification is redundant, but if we insist: $$A_\text{new} =\{2^x\in\mathbb N:x\in\mathbb N\}.$$

> $$S = \left\{...,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},1,2,4,...\right\}$$

\begin{align}S &=  \{2^x:x\in\mathbb Z\}\\&=\{n : \exists x {\in} \mathbb{Z}\;n=2^x\}.\end{align}

> $$B = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : \forall x \in \mathbb{N} \color\red{\text{ and }} n=2^x\}$$

Similarly as the above, because the abbreviation $\text“\forall x{∈}\mathbb N\text”$ is short for “for each natural $x,\ldots\text”,$ the above line is not meaningful until we delete the “and”:
\begin{align}B_\text{new} &=  \{n \in \mathbb{N} : \forall x {\in} \mathbb{N}\;n=2^x\}\\&=\text{the set of naturals such that }\textbf{each}\text{, for 
 }\textbf{every}\text{ natural $x,$ equals $2^x$}\\&=\emptyset,\end{align} noting that no natural number simultaneously equals $2, 4, 8,$ etc.

---

**Reply to @lone student's queries above**

> Why is this meaningless, exactly? $$B_1 = \{n : n=2^x, x \in \mathbb{N_{>0}}\}$$

This isn't meaningless per se: it says that each element of $B_1$ equals $2^x$ and that $x$ is natural. Here, we are given insufficient information (for example, we don't know whether every $x$ belongs to $\{3,7,14\}$) to fully specify $B_1;$ in contrast, the variable $x$ in each of these sentences is bound:

- for each $x,$ (each element of $B_1$ equals $2^x$ and $x$ is natural)
- for some $x,$ (each element of $B_1$ equals $2^x$ and $x$ is natural)
- each element of $B_1,$ for each natural $x,$ equals $2^x$
- each element of $B_1,$ for some natural $x,$ equals $2^x.$

> Is this incorrect/meaningless? $$B_2 = \{2^n\mid n\in\mathbb N_{>0}\}$$

This sentence is meaningful; as a matter of fact, $B_2=A_\text{new}.$

Comment: Thank you for the specific points, voted .